# Evans PDE prerequisite

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

In Appendix C of Evans's PDE textbook, lots of results about the boundary of open and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and surface integrals against such boundaries are mentioned. Is there any reference (textbook) that covers these results?

More precisely, I am looking for a textbook (with level as elementary as possible) such that:

1. The textbook defines the boundary in the same way (or a similar way) with Evans (i.e. if possible no manifolds or differential forms).
2. The textbook defines the surface integral using such a definition of boundary.
3. The textbook then proves more or less all results mentioned in Appendix C.

Comment: You will note that Evans calls this appendix "Calculus".  The material in that section is treated in a very elementary manner in most "Calculus" texts (e.g. first-year calculus in the American university system), and is treated in more detail in "advanced calculus" or "analysis" classes (with, maybe, a little bit of topology thrown in).  Pretty much any text with "analysis" or "advanced calculus" in the title should cover the material in sufficient detail (e.g. Rudin, Spivak, Apostol, Folland, etc).

Comment: I know every book you proposed. They do not fit the requirements.

Comment: Then you are going to have to make your question more clear.  To my eye, everything I need for reading Evan's appendix on calculus is well-trod material in pretty much any intro analysis text, plus maybe a few pages of a topology text.  The notational conventions may be slightly different, but the text is in the AMS "Graduate Studies in Mathematics" series---by the time you are reading graduate texts, it is assumed that you have the mathematical maturity and ability to translate notation.

Comment: Any multivariable calculus textbook